# show loader while downloading data from web services and updating the tableview using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to show loader while downloading the data from the web and loading into the table and the code should be placed in common place so that we can call that from any view controller. Please help me if any one knows something on this.

Comment: Maybe you can use the single instance pattern, place the code in a class, and you can call these code with this class's shared instance from any view controller.

Comment: you can try using SVProgressHud : https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD

Comment: I have tried with MBprogressHUD but its not loading before updating the tableview

Comment: And how can I place this code in appdelegate so that I can call it from any view controller.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the storyboard. And then can use its `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` functions.
- You can also use `UIProgressView` and can use its function `setProgress` to show how much progress is done

Comment: How do you figure out what value to send to ```setProgress```?

Comment: @Dan: Its all from webservice received data.